# Q&A: How does msg.sender actual address vary during the call?

Tags: contract-development, contract-invocation, ethereum-classic

**This part of own Q&A serial of posts which shares knowledge gained during work on one project**

`msg.sender` brought some ambiguity to me as at the first look this is an address of user caller. However, when a approve another user's address to operate with my test token, contract that perform this operation failed to this and ended up as a reverted tx.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By using `ether.js` you could call `contract.connect(<signer>)` to change the context, in other words `msg.sender` address.

This signer should be a wallet/account, it could not be another contract. However when inside your contract this contract calls another contract `msg.sender` **would be an address of the contract caller** – not an address which was defined during the initial call, e.g. `contract.connect(<signer>)`.

It might be important during `ERC721` token approve call: we could approve one address, but eventually authorized `ERC721` token function would be called by deployed contract which would end up with revered tx as this address has not been approved.

In short: `msg.sender` it is an address of contract caller - it would be a user's address who calls the contract or the contract's address who calls another contract despite on the origin caller is the user.